# react native wifi reborn - connected to wifi, but no internet available with exclamation mark

Tags: react-native, wifi

'''

```
const connectToSSID = () => {

            ToastAndroid.show('Connecting', ToastAndroid.LONG)

            WifiManager.connectToProtectedSSID(ssid, password, isWep).then(
                (res) => {
                    console.log("Accounts / connectToSSID / status ===> Connected successfully!");
                    ToastAndroid.show(`Connected to ${ssid}`, ToastAndroid.LONG)
                    setConnectionStatus(true)
                    // WifiManager.forceWifiUsageWithOptions(true,{noInternet: false}) 
                },
                (err) => {
                    console.log("Accounts / connectToSSID / status ===> Connection failed! ");
                    console.log("Error ===> ", err);
                    // ToastAndroid.show(err, ToastAndroid.LONG)
                }
            )
        }
```

'''

I can connect suddecsfully to my wifi network, but after connecting, the internet is not available.
[an exclamation mark is present as shown in the photo.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ss7IO.png)

[here is the wifi connection in UI system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wtldd.png)

is there anyway I can solve this?
thank you

Comment: I'm having the same problem even using forceWifiUsageWithOptions from Android 12. (Working in Android 10) Did you found something?